# Magento REST API Integrate

Tags: magento-1, rest-api

I want Magento API Integration but this issue appeared :

> oauth token not generate.

please help

```
hostname=http://www.fast-option.com/low/magento/admin/
callbackurl=http://www.fast-option.com/low/magento/category_tree.php

user=admin
pass=saudi@123
```

Comment: Hi @anurag , where are you facing this issue? while creating integration in admin?